# How can I store a string Matrix inside an array?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I have to store a `String` **matrix(3x20)** inside an `array` whose `length` may vary.
I am trying the following code but I am getting an `incompatible types` error.

How could I fix this error?

My code is:

```java
int x=0;    
String[] arrayF=new String[10];    
arrayF[x]= new String[3][20];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign array this way. You should eventually assign each element of the first 2-array to the 1-d array.

Something like:

```
String[][] array2D =new String[M][N];
String[] array1D = new String[M * N];

for (int i = 0 ; i < M ; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
    {
         array1D[(j * N) + i] = array2D[i][j];
    }

}
```

Comment: take care of naming convention `2dArray` `1dArray`

Answer (score 0):

`arrayF` is an **array of strings**, so each element in `arrayF` must be a string (by definition of the array).
What you are trying to do is is put an array (`new String[3][20]`), instead of a string, in each element of `arrayF`, which obviously contradicts it's definition (hence the `incompatible types` error).
One solution for what you want might be using a 3-d array of strings:

```
String[][][] arr = new String[10][3][20];
```

Answer (score 0):

arrayF is one dimensional array with String type.
You cannot add two dimensional array to arrayF. For dynamic array size, you should use ArrayList.

```
List<String[][]> main = new ArrayList<String[][]>();

String[][] child1 = new String[3][20];
String[][] child2 = new String[3][20];
main.add(child1);
main.add(child2);
```

Refer to
[Variable length (Dynamic) Arrays in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426671/variable-length-dynamic-arrays-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

use something like this:

```
String [][] strArr = new String[3][20];
ArrayList<String[][]> tm = new ArrayList<String[][]>();
tm.add(strArr);
```