# How to create Dynamic Two Dimensional Array [JAVA]

Tags: java, list, multidimensional-array

I am new to java and I want to create a 2-dimensional array in which the rows are static but the columns are dynamic.

```
double [][] lastSecArray = new double [2][41];
int lastValue = -1;
public foo (){
   lastValue++;
   lastSecArray[0][lastValue] = st_ms;
   //more code here
}
```

The value of lastValue increases and when it reaches 41 my program gives me Array Index out of bound. Which is what I should expect.

How can I make the column of teh array dynamic so that no matter how large the value of lastValue increases it runs.

Comment: An array of `ArrayList`... but since Java doesn't allow array of generic (you can create non-generic `ArrayList[]`, but there will be warning about type safety), so `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>` (both rows and columns are dynamic, but you don't need to worry about the rows anyway)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be more appropriate to use a `Map<Double, List<Double>>`.  Having the value of the `Map` as a `List<Double>` will allow you to expand the list as opposed to an array which has a fixed size.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    Map<Double, List<Double>> myMap = create(1, 3);
}

public static Map<Double, List<Double>> create(double row, double column) {
    Map<Double, List<Double>> doubleMap = new HashMap<Double, List<Double>>();

    for (double x = 0; x < row; x++) {
        for (double y = 0; y < column; y++) {
            doubleMap.put(x, new ArrayList<Double>());
        }
    }
    return doubleMap;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use

```
Map<String, ArrayList> lastSecArray = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList value = new ArrayList();
    value.add(0);
    value.add(1);
    value.add(2);
    lastSecArray.put("0", value);
```

so you can operate with

```
lastSecArray.size()
```

or

```
lastSecArray.put(...)
```

or array in array

Answer (score 1):

Use [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead.

You can use:

```
List<List<Double>> = new ArrayList<>();
```

`ArrayList` is dynamically-extendable. You can create `ArrayList` both for rows and cols.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're coming from the C-world. In Java, you have many objects which represent arrays.

I suggest you to check this link : [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). This is a class which uses a resizable array.

I think this is a good way to have a dynamic two dimensionnal Array in Java.

As ArrayList is a template class, you are able to create `ArrayList<ArrayList<double>>`, or if you want to have a "static" number of rows, you can create `ArrayList<double[2]>`.

Answer (score 0):

in Java arrays are fixed size so what you are saying is not possoble.

take a look at this thread might help you.

[Variable length (Dynamic) Arrays in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426671/variable-length-dynamic-arrays-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the element size at runtime

```
int size=runtime decides;
double [][] lastSecArray = new double [2][size];
```