# String Array With Custom Adapters

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-adapterview

Can we use String array with custom adapter and data should be display in Listview?

I mean something like that

```
 String [] s= {"cars","bike","train"};
```

Now how this string array will attach with Custom adapter and how data will show in the `ListView`.

I know this is easy with `ArrayList`.

But I want to do it with simple String Array.

Comment: Yes, you can.  The array is such a common use case that there is already a class for that: `ArrayAdapter`.  `ArrayAdapter` has a constructor that takes an array as well as a constructor that takes a list.    So you don't even need a custom adapter.  For the *custom* adapter, you can use *anything* as the base model for the list; it's the `ListAdapter` interface methods that make the model look like a list to the `ListView`.

Comment: I agree with you that by array adapter class we can do that...but my question is can we do this by custom adapter?

Comment: Absolutely yes you can.

Comment: Please can you write some code for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can use a custom adapter for that. But you could also use the `ArrayAdapter` class if you just want to show text on your `ListView`.

But, if for whatever reason you want to create a custom adapter, try the following...

In this particular case I'm subclassing the [`BaseAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) class.

This custom adapter will take hold of my data model, and will inflate the data to my `ListView` rows.

First, I'll create the XML of my custom row. You can see the code below.

**item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test text"
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here I've created a row that displays a text.

Now, I'll create my custom adapter to handle this XML. As you can see below.

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = MyAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context context_;
    private ArrayList<String> items;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> items) {
        this.context_ = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context_.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_mail, null);
        }

        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv);

        String text = items.get(position);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Text: " + text);

        tv.setText(text);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Ok. Now we have everything to make this work. In your `Activity` class, do something like that:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:id="@+id/tv_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_header">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add item"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listView" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private int numItem = 1; // Dummy int to create my items with different numbers.

    private MyAdapter myAdapter; // Your custom adapter.

    private ArrayList<String> items; // This is going to be your data structure, every time you change it, call the notifyDataSetChanged() method.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        items = new ArrayList<>();
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this,items);
        lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addItem(); // The method I'm using to insert the item. Look for it below.
            }
        });
    }

    private void addItem() {
        items.add("Text " + numItem++);

        mailAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Notifying the adapter that my ArrayList was modified.
    }
}
```

This should do the trick.

---

From what you told me, you want to use a `String` array instead of a `ArrayList<String>`. Well, change the adapter to the following.

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = MyAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context context_;
    private String[] items;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] items) {
        this.context_ = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    // Rest of the code... Same as before.
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private MyAdapter myAdapter; // Your custom adapter.

    private String[] items;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        items = {"Whatever","String","You","Like"};
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this,items);
        lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
}
```

**The problem with this approach:** Your adapter will have a fixed size, which will be the size of your String array once you create it. And you won't be able to make it bigger, unless you create another adapter with a different `String` array.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426671/variable-length-dynamic-arrays-in-java) discusses this matter.

Comment: Mauker I agree but can that code work  for string array instead of array list?

Comment: It is possible. Just swipe the ArrayList for your String array and change a few methods. But there is a major problem with this approach. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Done. That should do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84581/discussion-between-mauker-and-jitender).