# Increase array size, large enough to hold another array

Tags: java, arrays

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to increase size a of an array A so that A has a large enough buffer at the end to hold an array B.

Assuming the two sorted arrays are `A = {1, 3, 5}` and `B = {2, 4, 6, 8}`

`A = {1, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0}` and `B = {2, 4, 6, 8}` where A has buffer `{0, 0, 0, 0}` at the end to hold B

Comment: you cannot increase array size, it has a fixed length

Comment: I suggest thinking about `Lists`

Comment: you cant increase an array in java, use `Lists` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable length (Dynamic) Arrays in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426671/variable-length-dynamic-arrays-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot resize an array, you have to either construct a new array with the size of both arrays combined, or use another data structure (e.g. ArrayList).

Also see: [Make copy of array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785745/make-copy-of-array-java)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a literal array you have no chance of increasing its size in place. You must create a new array and copy A over it, perhaps by using [System.arrayCopy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29%).