# How to declare an array without having to give a fixed initial size in java?

Tags: java, arrays, exception, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to declare an array without having to give a fixed initial size, cause I want to accept the size from the user. Here's the latest method I came up with. I could give a maximum accepted value while declaring but I don't want to do that as it's a poor use of space.

```
class Example{
    int i;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Example(){
        System.out.println("in constructor");
        System.out.println("enter array size: ");
        i = in.nextInt();
    }
    int[] arr = new int[i];
    void perform(){
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
            arr[j] = in.nextInt();
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
            System.out.println(arr[j]);
    }
}
public class Main{  
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Example obj = new Example();
        obj.perform();
    }
}
```

The output is like this:-

in constructor
enter array size:
5
1 // This is me trying to enter the first element of the array.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable length (Dynamic) Arrays in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426671/variable-length-dynamic-arrays-in-java)

Comment: Not sure this works as `i` will be `0` when your array is created. Assign your array in your constructor.

Comment: Even after giving a fixed value of `i` in the constructor, the same error is appearing.

Comment: @SamagraDev Please include your modifications by editing your post. Don't overwrite what is currently there, just add it to the bottom of your question.

Comment: I didn't overwrite anything. I just added the output in the question, without making any changes to what was written initially. @Dioxin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

1. Declare `arr` without any size and as an instance variable.
2. Initialize `arr` in the constructor with size entered by the user.

Also, it's better to have the condition for the `for` loop inside `perform()` as `j < arr.length` so that it depends purely on the size of `arr` and not on the value of `i` which might change in some other part of the program. For the same reason, I have declared `i` as a local variable inside the constructor so that its scope is limited to the constructor only (where it is required) and nowhere else.

**Code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Example {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] arr;

    Example() {
        System.out.println("in constructor");
        System.out.println("enter array size: ");
        int i = in.nextInt();
        if (i >= 0) {
            arr = new int[i];
        }
    }

    void perform() {
        System.out.println("Enter " + arr.length + " integers");
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
            arr[j] = in.nextInt();
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
            System.out.println(arr[j]);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example obj = new Example();
        obj.perform();
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
in constructor
enter array size: 
2
Enter 2 integers
10
20
10
20
```

Answer (score 1):

Just declare it as `int[] arr;` but allocate it as soon as you know `i` is valid (i.e. > 0). Then you can use `arr.length` for your loops:

```
Example() {
    int i; // Local
    do {
        System.out.println("enter array size: ");
        i = in.nextInt();
    } while (i <= 0);
    arr = new int[i];
}

void perform() {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        arr[j] = in.nextInt();
    }
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an array, you can use a list without having to declare the size. You can then add items on the fly.
Your arr would be replaced by

```
ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

You could then add items like

```
myList.add(in.nextInt());
```

and access elements at a specific index using

```
myList.get(index);
```

So, in your case, it would look like this

```
ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
void perform(){
    for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
        myList.add(in.nextInt());
    for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
        System.out.println(myList.get(j));
}
```

Comment: @AlexRundenko It wouldn't compile in any version, since Java doesn't support primitive generic types. However, it would compile if using `Integer`.

Comment: @AlexRudenko Already edited. Meant to use `Integer` instead of `int`. You also need to `import java.util.ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use `List` instead of arrays, no need for initial size and you can just insert elements as much as you want

```
List<Integer> arr = new LinkedList<Integer>();

arr.add(5);
....
//Use for loop for adding numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList is a better choice, that you can Initialize with no fixed size and it has some better attributes over classic array.

```
ArrayList<datatype> array_name = new ArrayList<datatype>();
```

sure you can add new index by

```
array_name.add(new array index name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize the array in the constructor after getting the size from the user. You are currently initializing the array before the user enters any input, at which point `i` has its default value of `0`. See the below code in action [here](https://ideone.com/2I4iSo).

```
private final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
private final int[] arr;
private final int i;
Example(){
    System.out.println("in constructor");
    System.out.println("enter array size: ");
    i = in.nextInt();
    arr = new int[i];
}
```